# Google auth Redirect Url mismatched ! Magento 2

Tags: login, magento-2.1, social

I have integrated social Login Plugin "Mageplaza" in my Project,for getting  google client Id I have to give Redirect Url, Can anyone help me out regarding this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google redirect Url will be :
https://hostname.com/pslogin/account/login/type/googleplus/

1. we need to check whether both(redirect and domain) urls are http or https, It must be same.
2. if You are finding any error the error itself containing the expected redirect url.